Clicking a button with Selenium
There is a bounty game I'm playing, the price doesn't have a specific time of appearing. I want to use Selenium to click the "collect" button when it appears, it is first come, first served.
I tried JavaScript but feel like Python and Selenium will be faster. The problem I'm having is I don't know how to keep a watch on the button and click it when it appears. Whenever selenium tries to click the button before it appear the code will crash.
driver.get("https://example.com")
collectButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"collect")
collectButton.click()

I don't know if it's possible to keep click looping the above button until when it's available with the code crashing.

FYI polling client-side with setInterval will be much faster so if this is a race the javascript will win

One way to do this is to check for the existence of the button in a loop.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://example.com")
while True:
    button = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"collect")
    if button:
        button[0].click()
    time.sleep(0.5)


Ok Thanks, I will try it out and come back with feedback

Try using WebDriverWait (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to wait for the button to become clickable (when it appears and its visible)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://example.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
while True:
    try:
        button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "collect")))
        button.click()
        print("button clicked!")
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

